# Make git pull show relative path to the current directory for updated files

Tags: git, relative-path, git-pull

If my current directory is a subdirectory of a git project and I call `git pull` it always shows a path relative to the project root. Is there a way to see changed file paths relative to current directory?

Ex.

```
<root>/default $ git pull
...
Updating 03e5eb12..95987ffb
Fast-forward

../client/styles/components/manageEscrow.styles.ts               |  11 +++++
./lib/index.ts                                                   |   8 ++--

INSTEAD OF
client/styles/components/manageEscrow.styles.ts                  |  11 +++++
default/lib/index.ts                                             |   8 ++--
```

Comment: the example given isn't clear, given 'instead of' shows one file with a `default/` prefix and one without. can you please clarify what currently happens and what you want to happen?

Comment: @AD7six his current working directory is `/default`. Those are the desired relative paths to `/default`. He does not want to see the "absolute" paths to the git root directory `/`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't an option for this.  Git runs the diff machinery to produce this, and beyond the ability to control whether it's printed at all, there aren't any knobs to control it.

If, knowing that, you'd rather not see it, you can set either `merge.stat` or `merge.diffstat` to `false`, and Git will not produce it.

If this is a feature you want, the Git list would probably be open to a patch.